# Jquery leaderboard difference calculation

Tags: jquery, difference, leaderboard

I am working on Leaderboar table project. I need calculate leaders position on this week from last week position.

For example, if user is 1 place on this week, but on last week on 3 place, difference is `+2` on green.

Problem is that, that i have no CMS data from last week position, I can get only result points that is set on columns.

Is there a way to calculate hidden fields, values, from columns points and after that make different column with `+` and `-` place counts:

```
100 - 2 place    250 - 3 place = -1 
50 - 1 place     350 - 2 place = -1
200 - 3 place    400 - 1 place = +2
```

Here is my starting demo code: http://jsfiddle.net/Y2DS5/43/ also count is showing wrong difference.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert it into an integral value using `parseInt()`:

```
$(".mytable tr").not(":first").each(function() {
  // Use this: vvvvvv------------------------------------vvvv
  var td1 = parseInt($(this).children("td.pricea").text(), 10),
      td2 = parseInt($(this).children("td.priceb").text(), 10),
      difference = (td1 - td2),
      absNum = Math.abs(difference),
      largerNum = td1 > td2 ? td1 : td2,
      percentage = (absNum / largerNum).toFixed(2);

  if (difference < 0)
    $(this).children("td.out").text(percentage).addClass("green");
  else
    $(this).children("td.out").text(percentage).addClass("red");
});
```

**Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kx20s917/**

Comment: 83 90 result is 0.08, not 7.

Comment: @Foxsk8 Giving `parseFloat()` also gives the same result.

Comment: Yee. Demo is taken with procents, but i need a count + or -

Comment: I still don't get you.

Comment: I want to show postion change difference with count up or down position +2 or -4 places positions.